# Custom Render function in JSX - How to handle fragments

Tags: javascript, jsx

I'm trying to use JSX by itself (without React) to render some dynamic content, with a custom createElement function. I'm using webpack with the following setting: `{ "pragma": "createElement", "pragmaFrag": "'fragment'" }` for  `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`.

here is my custom renderer code:

```js
function createElement(tagName, attrs = {}, ...children) {
    let el = document.createElement(tagName);

    if (attrs) {
        for (let [ key, val ] of Object.entries(attrs)) {
            if (key === 'className') {
                el.className = val;
            } else {
                el.setAttribute(key, val);
            }
        }
    }

    for (let child of children) {
        if (Array.isArray(child)) el.append(...child);
        else el.append(child);
    }

    return el;
}
```

I'm curious how i could handle fragment elements (`<>content</>`) in this function. By googling, I've found people adding the following:

```js
function createElement() {
  // ...
  if (tagName === 'fragment') return children;
  // ...
  return el;
}
```

but this just returns the string `"[object HTMLLIElement]"`, which makes since to me since it seems that `createElement` must return *one* node element and not a NodeList or array of some sort.

Is there a way to easily implement fragments in my createElement function? Thanks

edit:

Using T.J.'s answer below, i was able to fix the problem by adding the following line to make use of [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment):

```js
    let el = tagName === 'fragment' ? new DocumentFragment() : document.createElement(tagName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much up to you how you handle it, since you also (presumably) wrote the code that uses what your `createElement` returns (e.g., putting those things in the DOM — your equivalent of `ReactDOM.render` or similar). You could return an array, or a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), or your own custom container. Whatever it is, your code that takes these and puts them in the DOM just has to check for it and handle it appropriately.

I should note that `createElement` doesn't generally create DOM elements directly. It creates objects (typically) that have the information to create elements, but not actual elements. One reason for that is that you don't always turn those objects into DOM elements; if you're updating rather than mounting, you're often updating your existing DOM elements based on updated information in the objects. Of course, you can do it differently, there's no "wrong" here. :-) I mention it because knowing that may help you with your fragment issue.

Comment: I didn't write the render function that calls `createElement` so I'm assuming that it's using whatever the JSX default function is, but I've been having a hard time figuring out where that lives or what it looks like. However, I didn't realize `Document.fragment` was a thing though, and that worked perfectly!

Comment: @nikarc - Glad that worked! FWIW, JSX doesn't really have anything to do with that function, it's just a feature of whatever you have that's *using* the results of the JSX. I'm interested that you don't know what function that is; how are you mounting your code in the DOM?

Comment: I guess my confusion is based on the fact that I'm not directly calling `createElement` in my code, and the fact that I'm setting the `pragma` setting for `plugin-transform-react-jsx`, i just assumed it was jsx calling the `createElement` function.  My jsx is mounted by calling: `const navigation = Navigation(navData); nodeEl.replaceWith(navigation)
`. `Navigation` being my top-level jsx, `navData` being json data, and `nodeEl` being a DOM element

Comment: @nikarc - Sorry, I may have confused you a bit there. Yes, when you do `<div>...</div>` in JSX, you're calling your `createElement` function; the JSX becomes `createElement("div", {})`. The other half I was talking about is the equivalent of `ReactDOM.render` or similar. In your case, your equivalent to *that* is `nodeEl.replaceWith(navigation)`. :-) So you're taking the output of your `createElement` and using it directly in the DOM. That's slightly different from what React and others do; they have an intermediate form so they can efficiently do a difference between what's in the DOM...

Comment: ...and what needs to be updated, since rebuilding the entire DOM each time can be slow. (That isn't intended to be criticism, not in any way. Just explanation.) So, mystery solved. Thanks for letting me know, I was curious. Happy coding!

Comment: @nikarc - Just as a side note, beware that if you do it the way you are, it makes reusing the result of `createElement` problematic. That's something that's perfectly fine in React (for instance), so I just thought I'd mention it. ([Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/vnupqekh/)) But it's your project and not being able to reuse them is not a problem if you're not planning to reuse them. :-)

Comment: Thanks T.J.! I super appreciate the explanation and it definitely makes more sense to me now. I have no need to reuse the resultant dom element from my `createElement` function, as its just being used once on the site for a small nav menu and it isnt rendering very much JSX at all. I'll keep an eye out though, and if I notice any slowdown ill find another solution. Thanks!

Comment: @nikarc - Really happy to help. I'm sure you'll be fine for a simple use case like that. Happy coding!